# Why isn't my button working on the simulator? XCode 12 swift

Tags: swift, xcode, button

This is the code I am using, I am trying to follow a tutorial but I don't know why the button won't work on the simulator. If anyone could explain why it is doing this as well that would be super helpful!

```
@IBAction func didTapAddButton(){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "date_picker") as! DateViewController
    vc.title = "New Event"
    vc.completionHandler = { [weak self] name, date in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            didCreateEvent(name: name, targetDate: date)
    }
        self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you checked `didTapAddButton` is being called by adding a break point/print in the function?

Comment: I haven't done this no, I will give it a try. Where do you recommend I place the break point? @Andrew

Comment: Inside `didTapAddButton`, probably on the `let vc = ...` line.

Comment: Try adding a `print("button pressed")` right after `@IBAction func didTapAddButton(){`. Are you using a navigation controller? If not, `pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` won't work.

Comment: Define "won't work". Is the method even called? Is `self.navigationcontroller` nil? Is it crashing? If so, which line? First one? What's the error message in console?

Comment: Won't work = it didn't go through to the second view controller. On the main storyboard I changed the action to go to this as the tutorial didn't explicitly include this. (I am very new to all of this and I am trying to teach myself how to code and I'm not used to the lingo yet either). There was no error message I think it may have been the wrong connection (sorry if that doesnt make sense)

Comment: @GeorginaBrough np. Can you screenshot what your storyboard looks like? Also, check the Connections Inspector (the rightmost tab on the attributes inspector) to see if your outlet is connected.

Comment: Where you wrote `self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`, just before: `print("self: \(self) - navVC: \(self?.navigationController)")`, what's the output?